# why IIS showing 403 forbidden error when using VS2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I am developing an ASP.NET web application using .NET Framework 4 and Oracle 11g at back end in Visual Studio 2012. IIS 8 Express is configured to deploy the web app. When I try to run the app from Visual Studio 2012, I got an error HTTP Error code 403.14 (See below screenshot:)
[image]

I googled for solution but it's not working. I have already enabled Directory Browsing in as Microsoft suggests to do so on error page but still I am getting the above error. Please help me out here.

Comment: We can only guess unless you show us your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

First, enabling Directory Browsing is not a wise solution because you could compromise the security of your website by exposing internal information.  Secondly, the cause of this error is typically as stated in the first part of the "Most likely causes" for the error page (emphasis mine):

> **A default document is not configured for the requested URL**, and
>   directory browsing is not enabled on the server.

In my experience, it is the result of using `Default.aspx` or `Index.aspx` as your main page, which - oddly enough - are not in the "default documents" list by default.  This has always seemed like a poor design choice to me, but it should be relatively simple to modify the configuration and add whatever default page name you are using to the list.

Comment: I do not have any default.aspx or index.aspx. I have two basic pages, LoginUI.aspx and Register.aspx. When I tried to LoginUI.aspx as my startup page, still problem is not resolved. Even if you just want to run the specific page by View in Web Browser right clicking on page, it's showing "404-Not Found"

Comment: When you choose "View in Web Browser" what URL is sent to the browser?  What browser are you testing your pages with?

Comment: Do you have form authentication enabled in the web.config?

Comment: I have solved this problem. This occurs generally for not setting the Page as startup page. Thanks all for your help